# Select box in does not bind to component.ts

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to bind my select box to a variable using this code:

**TS FILE**

```
public selectedPlaza: string;
plazaList: Plaza[];

submitParameters(): void {
    debugger;
    console.log(this.selectedPlaza);
}
```

**HTML FILE**

```
 <div class="pr-1">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Plaza</label>
            <Select type="text" class="form-control" #select (change)="valueChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="selected">
              <option [ngValue]='0' [selected]>All Plaza</option>
              <option *ngFor="let item of plazaList" [ngValue]='item.plazaCode'>{{item.plazaName}}</option>
            </Select>
          </div>
        </div>
```

For some reason when I log the selectedPlaza it gives me undefined. What can I try in order to resolve this?

Comment: Perhaps you can try and define `public selectedPlaza: Plaza;` instead of as `string`. This is due to the `plazaList` is of type `Plaza` and the ngModel is binding to that.

Comment: Unless if you have added an extra function to define `item.plazaName` to `selectedPlaza` on selected value.

Comment: @Ibanez1408 Please check my code and let me know does it serve your purpose or not. Best wishes. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, I have a solution for you please check the code below. Check the [Stackblitz Link too](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-selectoption-jrr9lf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) =>

**HTML:**

```
 <select [(ngModel)] ="selected"
            name="valueCheck" 
            (change)="valueChange($event)"> 
            <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled [selected]>Select Any </option>
            <option *ngFor="let obj of plazaList" [ngValue]="obj" > {{obj.plazaName}} </option>
 </select>
```

**TS:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  
  plazaList=[];
  selected:any;
  constructor(){
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      let temp=new Plaza();
      temp.plazaCode='pc-'+i.toString();
      temp.plazaName='p-'+i.toString();
      this.plazaList.push(temp);
    }
  }

  valueChange(event){
    console.log("selected value",event.target.value ,
    'value of selected',this.selected);
  }
}
export class Plaza{
  plazaName:string;
  plazaCode:string;
}
```

Comment: I will try this out as soon as I get to my PC.

Comment: @Ibanez1408 Best of luck. If you still face any problem please let me know :-)

Comment: Sir, I changed the code the way you coded it. The event actually fires up but it's not giving me the right value. I need the plazaCode but it's giving me the plazaName. Please see my edit and the "selected" is still undefined.

Comment: change `{{item.plazaName}}` into {{item.plazaCode}} @Ibanez1408

Comment: the item.PlazaCode did not work for me. I just changed the [ngValue] to [value] then it worked. Thank you so much Sir.

Comment: Well done @Ibanez1408 I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved. :-)